# Crash when UIAlertView dismissed

Tags: ios, crash, uialertview

1. I am using ARC.
2. I show an alert view after a user taps a UITableView cell.
3. 99% of the times everything works great.

**NOW TO THE WEIRED PART**

I have this view hierarchy -

UITableView --> First UIViewController --> Child UIViewControllerControllers

The crash only appears after I open one, specific child UIViewControllers. After I enter all the other child viewControllers the alert view works great. If I enter the "problematic" view controller even once, The UIAlert view will crash even 5 minutes later and even if I get into all the other view controllers.

I have to say again that the alertView is presented in the root UITableView. And that it crashes even if the alert view callback method is only NSLoging.

The crash report is:

```
 *** -[ReviewViewController isKindOfClass:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x20bea8d0
```

while 'ReviewViewController' is the problematic viewController.

Thanks

Shani

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting the delegate of the `UIAlertview` to the calling `UIViewController`. That `UIViewController` is being de-allocated in certain cases when you navigate away from it.

If you require a delegate to respond to the `UIAlertView`, you'll have to structure your code so that the delegate doesn't get de-allocated before the `UIAlertView` will be dismissed.

Comment: The delegate is the UITable view controller, I checked it many times.

Comment: @shannoga I understand that. It's that UITableViewController that has been deallocated by the OS. The delegate property of UIAlertView is no doubt a weak reference, so ARC will allow for de-allocation of that viewcontroller when its no longer referenced.

Comment: The delegate of UIAlertView is NOT a weak reference, it is assign. See the documentation. Setting the delegate to nil in the ReviewViewController dealloc method might solve the crash.

Comment: @jbat100 What I don't understand is what is the connection to the ReviewController he is gone before I call the alert view ?

Comment: Well you were right, my fault, somehow I nill'ed the view controller. Fixed now. Thanks

Comment: @shannoga Hey glad to hear you found and fixed it. Also, thanks for coming back almost a month later and awarding the rep! It's much appreciated!